# My program works as intended I am removing a record from a data base and it works except for an Invalid column index exception

Tags: java

This is the sql statement. The error shows up as "pStat.setString(2, rp.getLegalDescription());"

```
private static final String REMOVE_OBJECT = "DELETE FROM RES where ID = ?";
```

This is the method for removing a row.

```
private boolean deletePreparedStatement(ResidentialProperty rp)
{
    try
    {
        /*
         * (long id, java.lang.String legalDescription, java.lang.String address, java.lang.String quadrant, java.lang.String zone, double askingPrice, java.lang.String comments, double area, double bathrooms, int bedrooms, char garage) 
         */

        PreparedStatement pStat = conn.prepareStatement(REMOVE_OBJECT);

        pStat.setLong(1, rp.getId());
        pStat.setString(2, rp.getLegalDescription());
        pStat.setString(3, rp.getAddress());
        pStat.setString(4, rp.getQuadrant());
        pStat.setString(5, rp.getZone());
        pStat.setDouble(6, rp.getAskingPrice());
        pStat.setString(7, rp.getComments());
        pStat.setDouble(8, rp.getArea());
        pStat.setDouble(9, rp.getBathrooms());
        pStat.setInt(10, rp.getBedrooms());
        pStat.setString(11, rp.getGarage()+"");
        pStat.setLong(12, rp.getId());

        int rowCount = pStat.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("row count = "+ rowCount);
        pStat.close();
        return rowCount == 1;
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

And this is the method to actually take it out of the database

```
public boolean remove(Object o)
{
    ResidentialProperty rp = (ResidentialProperty)o;
        try
        {
            PreparedStatement pstat = conn.prepareStatement(REMOVE_OBJECT);
            pstat.setLong(1, rp.getId());
            rs = pstat.executeQuery();
            rs.close();
            pstat.close();
        }catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return deletePreparedStatement(rp);
}
```

Lastly the error log looks as follows. Thank you very much for reading. I will continue to try and solve this as this gets posted

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
sucessful remove
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setStringInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5168)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setString(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5156)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setString(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:278)
at saitMLS.persistance.property.ResidentialPropertyBroker.deletePreparedStatement(ResidentialPropertyBroker.java:181)
at saitMLS.persistance.property.ResidentialPropertyBroker.remove(ResidentialPropertyBroker.java:455)
at saitMLS.problemDomain.property.UserInterface$2.actionPerformed(UserInterface.java:705)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need pass only `ID` alone to the `PreparedStatement` object because your SQL (`DELETE FROM RES where ID = ?`) accepts only one parameter (i.e., `ID`).

So keep only one (**ID**) parameter (shown below) in your `deletePreparedStatement` method and remove rest of the `pStat.setString`, etc.. parameters:

```
 pStat.setLong(1, rp.getId());
```

---

As a side note, I strongly suggest you to close the `PreparedStatement` objects in the finally block or use **try-with-resources**.